# How to ignore particular indices in a string while iterating over it?-py3

Tags: python-3.x

I have been working on a program that extracts text from brackets..
What i want to do is ignore particular indices in the string while iterating...

```
string="[x+[y]w+3333]"
lst1=[n1 for n1 in range(len(string)) if string.find("[", n1) == n1]
lst1.sort(reverse=True)#since the iteration begins with the "[" of highest index the list must be arranged in descending order
def find_brack2(brackplace):
  lst2=[n2 for n2 in range(len(string[brackplace:])) 
  if string[brackplace:].find("]", n2) == n2]
  lst2.sort()
  return (lst2[0]+brackplace)#returns the nearest "]"
lst=[]
for brack1 in lst1: 
  mainstring=string[brack1+1:find_brack2(brack1)]
  lst.append(mainstring)
print(lst)
```

The output:

```
 ['y', 'x+[y']
          ↑
```

As you can see it causes a problem. I want to ignore the string at `string [brack1:find_brack2(brack1)+1]` while iterating over the string.....Any help will be highly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `re` module in Python for ignoring the brackets in the sub-strings which you get based on the indices returned by your functions.

```
string="[x+[y]w+3333]"
lst1=[n1 for n1 in range(len(string)) if string.find("[", n1) == n1]
lst1.sort(reverse=True)#since the iteration begins with the "[" of highest index the list must be arranged in descending order
def find_brack2(brackplace):
  lst2=[n2 for n2 in range(len(string[brackplace:])) 
  if string[brackplace:].find("]", n2) == n2]
  lst2.sort()
  return (lst2[0]+brackplace)#returns the nearest "]"
lst=[]


for brack1 in lst1:
  print(brack1)
  print(find_brack2(brack1)) 
  mainstring=''.join(re.findall(r'[0-9a-zA-Z+]', string[brack1+1:find_brack2(brack1)]))

  lst.append(mainstring)
print(lst)
```

The output which you get with this is:

```
['y', 'x+y']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what i am tring to do is ignore 3,4,5 indices in the string while iterating. You see, doing that gives ['y',**'x+[y]w+3333**']                                                               
      ←   content in the next pair of brackets

Comment: Alright. If I got you correctly, you're interested in extracting the text from the brackets ('y') first and then representing the whole string without the brackets as well as the text inside it i.e. 'x + w + 3333'?